# Windows server 2012 sign out or disconnect?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am connected with RDP on a remote server.

I just want to leave and I have two options:
1) Sign out
2) Disconnect

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Always remember to Google first. Googling `windows server 2012 sign out disconnect` will get you everything you need in the very first link.

Comment: I already saw that "very first link" you propose, yet it clearly states "Applies To: Windows Server 2003, Windows Server 2003 R2, Windows Server 2003 with SP1, Windows Server 2003 with SP2", and also it does not mention "Sign out" instead it uses "Log off"...

Comment: Fair enough. As far as I know, it's the exact same thing though.

Comment: Thank you Pekka! I would give you the answer point if you made your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. Sign Out - interrupt sessions and all active programs started by you in session. Same as 'Log Off' or 'Log Out'.
2. Disconnect - all programs started by you in session remain active in background. You can reconnect, and continue using the same session.

Comment: why would you ever Sign Out? doesn't Disconnecting make login/logout times way faster?

Comment: @3pitt late reply but for scenarios where you have multiple users on one host consider that leaving a session running hogs resources (think load balancing) and makes updating applications harder because they are still running in your disconnected session. Your sysadmin will probably either force a logout or force a time limit on disconnected sessions to deal with that.